# Como puedo solucionar la firma del DTE

Tags: c#

Buenas gente tengo un sistema de facturas electrónicas(chile) y a momento de mandar el DTE al SII me rechaza la firma del dte siendo que envió los datos como los pide el SII
La respuesta me manda el trackid desde el SII pero no me da detalles
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Tenía ese mismo error y pueden ser varios factores:
-El certificado puede no coincidir con el rut que envía.
-El dte está mal firmado:

Podrías compartir tu código, es similar a este?

```
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc)
            {
                SigningKey = certificado.PrivateKey
            };

            Signature XMLSignature = signedXml.Signature;
            Reference reference = new Reference("");

            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
            XMLSignature.SignedInfo.AddReference(reference);
            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

            keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((System.Security.Cryptography.RSA)certificado.PrivateKey));
            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificado));
```